# How to linearize if, then constraint.

Tags: optimization, constraints, binary-programming

I want to model the following constraint:

- $x$ is a binary variable,
- $y$ and $z$ are positive variables,
- if $x=1$ then $y=z$.

I want to code this constraint in Gams.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{l}
y-z\leq (1-x)M\\
z-y\leq (1-x)M
\end{array}
$$

where $M$ is a sufficiently large constant.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to enforce $$x(y-z) = 0$$ since this implies that $x=0$ or $y-z=0$. Note, however, that this is not a linear constraint...